# Where does this definition of elliptical coordinates come from?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems

I've come across a definition for elliptical coordinates in terms of position vectors in the gravitational attraction by two fixed force centers while studying applications of the Hamilton Jacobi Equation that I haven't understood.

Here it goes

[image]

[image]

Why is it that $\xi \equiv r_1 + r_2$ and $\eta \equiv r_1 - r_2$? I don't follow.

Comment: It's just a convenient choice - convenient because xi   and eta are orthogonal.

Comment: One meaning of $\equiv$ is "defined as". That's the meaning in this case: $\xi$ is defined as $r_1 + r_2$ and $\eta$ is defined as $r_1 - r_2$. These turn out to be meaningful definitions. (If they weren't, they wouldn't be used.)

Comment: Ah, yes, I think David has correctly detected your problem: Those two equations you have issues with do not follow from any derivations. They reflect a choice, and as it turns out, a convenient one at that.

Comment: I think this is mathematics rather than physics, despite the motivation of motion resulting from gravitational attraction.

Comment: Possibly the reason for this choice of co-ordinate system is that the orbits of bodies in central gravitational fields are either ellipses or hyperbolas, each different orbit defined by fixed amounts of energy and angular momentum.

Answer (score 1):

The equations $\eta = r_1-r_2$, $\xi = r_1+r_2$ are simply a *choice* or definition. A *motivation* for the choice is that their level curves define the orthogonal family of hyperbolas ($\eta=const$) and ellipses ($\xi=const$).  In connexion with the latter, have you not seen the ["Pin and String" method for drawing an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Pins-and-string_method)? It is a direct embodiment of the assertion $\xi=const$ defines an ellipse.

They are a valid *local* definition of co-ordinates, which is shown as follows. There is a unique closed upper half plane point defined by $(\xi,\,\eta)$ whenever $r_1,\,r_2 \geq 0$, $\xi\geq 2 D$ and $|r_1-r_2|\leq 2 D$. To understand this, clearly $(\xi,\,\eta)$ defines a unique $(r_1,\,r_2)$ and then these latter define two circles centered at the focusses: if $r_1+r_2 > 2 D$ and $|r_1-r_2|\leq 2 D$, then the circles have exactly two intersections, one in the lower half plane and the other a reflexion of the first in the line joining the focusses. In the other direction: every half plane point can be shown to have a $(\xi,\,\eta)$ definition.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thanks, I think it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question; the proposed coordinate system is a legitimate coordinate system, in that it can appropriately map the plane. That's all that is required for a coordinate system. Further down in the passage you quoted it becomes clear that it's a good choice, too, since the coordinate lines correspond to physically meaningful orbits.

I even seem to dimly remember this from somewhere, long, looong time back in a celestial mechanics class, and I believe I remember that this is not an unusual coordinate system to use in those quarters.